# font not working in svg on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: libreoffice, fonts, gimp, svg

on ubuntu `18.04`, if I download a font `.ttf` file and copy it to the `~/.fonts` directory, the font appears in `libreoffice`; then I can save an `.svg` file with text using that font, and then loading the `.svg` file in `gimp` or `ristretto` image viewer, the font displays correctly;

on ubuntu `20.04`, doing the same as above, the font displays in libreoffice, but the `.svg` saved from libreoffice does not show the font correctly when loaded into gimp or ristretto; it does show correctly if loaded into libreoffice however;

I tried copying the font also to `/usr/local/share/fonts` and `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/` and `~/.local/share/fonts` but it makes no difference;

how can I get font `.ttf` files that I add to the system to work in `.svg` files in gimp at least on ubuntu 20.04 as they did in ubuntu 18.04 ?

Comment: Does `fc-cache -fv` both as your user and as root help?

Comment: I tried ```fc-cache -fv``` as my user, and it found the font  in the ~/.local/share/ and it said it cached it, but gimp and ristretto still don't see it when loading an .svg, and display another font instead; I also tried fc-cache -fv as root, and rebooting, and even saving the .svg again from libreoffice after the fc-cache -fv command but still no change; the .svg shows correctly only when loaded into libreoffice

Comment: What font does the svg show up as in Firefox/Chrome? If you inspect element and click the "Fonts" tab, what does it say?

Comment: I tried in the brave browser, and the font name shows correctly in the inspect, though it doesn't display correctly, so comparing the font visually, it displays as the Liberation font, which is the default in libreoffice. So I tried several different downloaded fonts, and they all display correctly. The only font that does not display correctly from .svg (except if loaded in libreoffice) is Atures